# bad access after creating character array

Tags: objective-c, arrays, memory-management

I seem to be hitting some limit within my application but I'm baffled.

Edited down, the problem code seems to be:

```
NSInteger tcMax = 9000000;  // 8 million here and all is ok. 9 or more = crash
char tcBuffer[tcMax];

[self doSomething];  // EXC BAD ACCESS here. Or whatever other line of code is here
```

I've pasted these lines into a fresh project and all's well, so it seems that there are other factors coming into play. Is there maybe a max to the total bytes that can be allocated by a particular method? Or some other limit that I could be tipping at around this 8 / 9 Mb point?

Comment: An array allocated like that ends up on the stack, where putting 8-9 Mb is really never a good idea. Use `malloc`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have my Mac in front of me, but I'm fairly certain that 9 MB is too large of a *stack allocation*.  You'll blow the stack (hence, Stack Overflow) with that much of memory allocation in a fixed size array. Convert to a *heap allocation*:

```
char* tcBuffer = (char*)malloc(tcMax);

[self doSomething];

// before the function/method returns call this:
free(tcBuffer);
tcBuffer = NULL;
```

iOS might have different behavior than MacOS in this regard.

Answer (score 0):

The dynamic programm memory is limited (the maximum varies).

For big arrays use `malloc` and `free` to use the heap.